# Hide All Other Context Menu When One Is Opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

It's jquery Context menu plugin.
working all fine but i need to hide all context menu 
when any other context menu is being opened.

here is link of the plugin [ContextMenuPluginLink](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html)

[image: One context menu should be hidden]

Comment: it's being called like this

$("#" + vdropdownOuterDivID).contextMenu(menu1SmallContainerDiv, { theme: ContextmnueType });

but it's not matter that how it's called because it's being called from 100 of places. i can't change each of them. so i have to modify the plugin otherwise i can create logic from it's calling point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve specific functionality, you need to assign unique id and common class to each context menu. On your given link there has been described how you can hide context menu manually.

[Hide context menu manually](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#hide-trigger)

What you can do is you can call hide method on already opened context menu like below:

```
$("#IdofOpenedMenu").contextMenu("hide");
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: i will let you know when i will apply this solution